# Issue with escaping quotes and curly brackets in bash script

Tags: bash, escaping, curly-braces, single-quotes

Issue with Escaping quotes and brackets in bash script
Running this

```
a="{\'copa\':\'copa2\'}"
print "$a"
```

The result is:

```
{'copa':'copa2'}
```

Using a in a sh command adds quotes arrount aws_instance_tag statement and removes the single quotes for copa values

```
sh "ansible-playbook playbooks/environment-provisioning.yml -e env=perf -e num_injectors_zone_a=2 -t performance_services -e aws_instance_tags=${a} "
```

Result

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/environment-provisioning.yml -e env=perf -e
num_injectors_zone_a=2 -t performance_services -e
'aws_instance_tags={copa:copa2}'
```

Comment: That shouldn't even run as your are passing the quoted string as an argument/file to sh. Assuming you used `-c` and it's a typo then your variable undergoes shell expansion twice, once when passed to sh, and once when run, removing the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of stringifying the command, try using an array:

```
# define the array
cmd=(
    ansible-playbook 
    playbooks/environment-provisioning.yml 
    -e env=perf 
    -e num_injectors_zone_a=2 
    -t performance_services 
    -e aws_instance_tags="$a"
)
# then run it
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: Such an elegant solution! I had to use `eval "${cmd[@]}"`.

Comment: Why is that? What happened when you did not use `eval`?

Comment: good point - generally no need for `eval`, but my command is (simplified) `sed -i "'/sorange/,/eorange/ { s/1/2/; s/A/B/ }'" file`, which fails on `sed` when no `eval`.

Comment: That's because there are two pairs of quotes. You don't need both single and double quotes.

Comment: I agree, if the command is just being run as is, but what I neglected to say is that it's to be run from a variable, so that I can have another variable inside the curly braces (`s/1/$v`).

Comment: There's still no need for the single quotes.

Comment: I've checked and that's correct, thanks: no single quotes, no `eval`. (Or if my superfluous single quotes are there, needs `eval`...)